# Model selection with different error distributions

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

I have three different models for a given set of data. Each of the models has a different error distribution. These error distributions are known.

How can I decide what is the best model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try comparing their AIC values (Akaike Information Criterion)

Comment: Yes, but how do I choose the likelihood function? It would be incorrect to choose mean square errors, since only one of the models has errors distributed following a gaussian.

Comment: You would use different likelihood functions corresponding to the different distributions of the error terms for each model.

Answer (score 0):

If the models have similar complexity, e.g. having the same number of parameters, then you can use different kind of criteria like KS distance or deviation on moments. For different model complexity use AIC or BIC. Ken is right on how to do it. For near-normal models and data the AIC is strongly correlated to moment deviations and e.g. Jarque-Bera value. KS distance is also OK, but only sensitive in the distribution center.